# How can I rename .TXT files to .OLD using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, text-files, rename

I need to rename my textfiles to .old format.
I'm new to C# and have no idea.
I haven't tried nothing yet because I don't even know where to start, so please no comments "What have you tried so far"?

Comment: You only want to rename the file?

Comment: You can easily google that: `rename file c#`

Comment: I got 24 million results on that google search and you found nothing??

Comment: Interesting. Which google have you used? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/435a2692-6161-4039-bfa9-5e6211d90c49/ First link when you type in "c# rename file"

Comment: It's always astonishing how much effort will be put into defending that no information could be found instead of put that effort into more research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.IO.File.Move(oldFileName, Path.ChangeExtension(oldFileName, 'old'));
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't copy, it's waste of time!

use this instead, it's equal to rename file name:

```
File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Dos rename command as well, but remember to set the working directory

```
string command = @"/c ren *.txt *.old";
ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
cmdsi.WorkingDirectory = @"d:\test"; //set your working directory
cmdsi.Arguments = command;
Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do it for you but you can use the static methods on System.IO.Path and System.IO.File to achieve this, now go forth and write an exploratory Console application.

Comment: You could have mentioned that there is no "Rename" method, but that "Move" can be used.

Comment: @feedwall I wanted to help the OP by showing them where to find their answer, but I think this is such a simple thing to discover by exploration that if they couldn't find the answer themselves then there would be no point in providing a code sample for use in a larger project...